# Does creating a system alert window using a service send top activity onPause

Tags: android, android-activity, android-framework

I am debugging some code where A service adds a system alert window on top of an activity as a result of a key event.

The window has input fields, for which the keyboard gets displayed which clears the fullscreen flags which the top activity had set when it was created.

This can only happen if the top activity wasn't sent to the background when the service added the system_alert_window on top of the activity.

Thus i wanted to confirm whether, an activity goes to background or onPause() when a system_alert_window is added on top of it, like would happen if an another activity starts on top of it.

Comment: Why you dont debug yourself? That had be more convinced to you becsuse you are seeing the log.

Comment: I did a dumpsys activity and the top activity still is on top even though an alert window is on top of it...also from the logs i can see onPause() is not getting called when the alert window opens or onResume when the alert window hides..still wanted to confirm from you guys  so is the situation that i described above about a fullscreen activity being turned into not_fullscreen by an overlaying alert window possible??

Comment: Aler doesn't stop an activity nor starting a  service from the activity

Comment: So you mean when an alert comes on top of an activity, that activity is still the top activity, partially visible..and the systemui can be modified by this window too??

Comment: Yes, if the alert is displayed from.that activity if its through service then you can use statis fields to access them or broadcase something to the activity

Comment: The alert is being displayed from another service running in the background...if instead of service, another activity from a different app, was adding the alert window on top of current top activity , will it pause the top activity?? sorry for bothering you but i am really in a fix right now

Comment: If you started an activity from the activity it will pause it. Im not sure you exactly want now, pause or not pausing the activity?

Comment: Let me explain the situation..an activity is currently running..now if another activity from another app , as a result of a key press creates a window on top of current running activity, will this send the current running activity to onPause(), the activity is visible in the background while the window is in front

Comment: Yes if another activity is started in top of your application, your app will go to the background.

Comment: A system alert will not cause the Activity to pause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did more research as part of an ongoing bug to modify AOSP.

In the process, i learnt that

- No opening an alert window on top of an activity shouldn't and doesn't send it to background or call onPause().
- The activity window is no more in focus, when an alert window gets opened on top of it, but the activity view is still visible, ie. view.visibility =VISIBLE.
- When the overlay window is exited, the activity window again gains focus.